# Is keras.initializers.ones() for style?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

From what I read, `tf.keras.initializers.ones()` is one of the initializers that initializes weights.

The 3 lines of code below generate the same tensors:

```
>>> a = tf.keras.initializers.ones()((1, 2))
>>> b = tf.ones((1, 2))
>>> c = tf.constant([[1., 1.]])
```

```
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: id=27, shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
>>> b
<tf.Tensor: id=30, shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
>>> c
<tf.Tensor: id=35, shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Looks like I can use `tf.ones((1, 2))` to get the same weight values. But I should still use the ones initializer to initialize the weights as good practice.

Want to make sure I didn't miss anything important here with the initializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [source of `tf.keras.initializers.ones`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L133-L171). It's mainly a call to `array_ops.ones`, which is the same as `tf.ones`. It also checks that the type is numeric or boolean.

Even though they seem equivalent, I would suggest using `tf.keras.initializers.ones` because it makes it that much clearer that you are using those values to initialize something.

Comment: The source code documentation shows an interesting example `def make_variables(k, initializer)`. Here is at least one reason for using the ones initializer: you can pass in different initializers knowing that they all confirm to the same API.